# How to realize parallel loop in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, parallel-processing, delphi-xe

How to realize parallel loop in Delphi  (Delphi 200X, Delphi XE) ? How to do this best way? And is there any universal solution?

With examples, please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the best solution at the moment is the Parallel For Loop construct in [OmniThreadLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/).  You pass it a collection, or a pair of integers representing lower and upper bounds, and an anonymous method representing the loop body, and it uses a thread pool to run the for loop in parallel.

Note that this will only work if the loop body method is capable of standing on its own.  If it modifies any external variables or relies on the value of a calculation made earlier in the loop then it can't be parallelized.

An introduction to the OmniThreadLibrary parallel for can be found [here](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/06/omnithreadlibrary-20-sneak-preview-1.html). For example, a simple for loop iterating over numbers looks like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(1, testSize).Execute(
  procedure (const elem: integer)
  begin
    // do something with 'elem'
  end);
```

Comment: Could post example of parallel loop realization using OmniThreadLibrart? Or link to example

Comment: @Astronavigator: See the link in the last paragraph for examples.

Answer (score 4):

If you need only ParallelFor you can use this code:

```
interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

type
  TParallelProc = reference to procedure(i: Integer; ThreadID: Integer);

  TParallel = class(TThread)
  private
    FProc: TParallelProc;
    FThreadID: Integer; //current thread ID
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    function GetNextValue: Integer;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    property Proc: TParallelProc
      read FProc write FProc;
    class var
      CurrPos: Integer; //current loop index
      MaxPos: Integer;  //max loops index
      cs: TCriticalSection;
      ThCount: Integer; //thread counter - how much threads have finished execution
  end;


{** ParallelFor Loop - all iterations will be performed in chosen threads
@param nMin - Loop min value (first iteration)
@param nMax - Loop max value (last iteration)
@param nThreads - how much threads to use
@param  aProc - anonymous procedure which will be performed in loop thread
}
procedure ParallelFor(nMin, nMax, nThreads: Integer; aProc: TParallelProc); overload;
{** ParallelFor Loop - all iterations will be performed in max cpu cores
@param nMin - Loop min value (first iteration)
@param nMax - Loop max value (last iteration)
@param  aProc - anonymous procedure which will be performed in loop thread
}
procedure ParallelFor(nMin, nMax: Integer; aProc: TParallelProc); overload;

implementation

uses
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  Windows,
  {$ENDIF}
  SyncObjs;

procedure ParallelFor(nMin, nMax, nThreads: Integer; aProc: TParallelProc);
var
  threads: array of TParallel;
  I: Integer;
begin
  if nMin > nMax then
    Exit;
  // initialize TParallel class data
  TParallel.CurrPos := nMin;
  TParallel.MaxPos := nMax;
  TParallel.cs := TCriticalSection.Create;
  TParallel.ThCount := 0;

  // create the threads
  SetLength (threads, nThreads);
  for I := 0 to nThreads - 1 do
  begin
    threads[I] := TParallel.Create; // suspended
    threads[I].FThreadID := I;
    threads[I].Proc := aProc;
    threads[I].Start;
  end;

  for I := 0 to nThreads - 1 do
  begin
    threads[I].WaitFor;
  end;

  for I := 0 to nThreads - 1 do
  begin
    threads[I].Free;
  end;

  TParallel.cs.Free;
end;

procedure ParallelFor(nMin, nMax: Integer; aProc: TParallelProc);
begin
  ParallelFor(nMin, nMax, CPUCount, aProc);
end;

{ TParallel }

constructor TParallel.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True); // suspended
  InterlockedIncrement(ThCount);
  FreeOnTerminate := False;
  FThreadID := 0;
end;

destructor TParallel.Destroy;
begin
  InterlockedDecrement(ThCount);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TParallel.Execute;
var
  nCurrent: Integer;
begin
  nCurrent := GetNextValue;
  while nCurrent <= MaxPos do
  begin
    Proc(nCurrent, FThreadID);
    nCurrent := GetNextValue;
  end;
end;

function TParallel.GetNextValue: Integer;
begin
  cs.Acquire;
  try
    Result := CurrPos;
    Inc(CurrPos);
  finally
    cs.Release;
  end;
end;
```

However, if you need more threading "stuff" you should consider using third party libraries.

Comment: What is so complicated to you? It's very simple solution IMO. Much simpler than using OmniThreadLibrary. You can write something like this: ParallelFor(0, Count - 1, procedure(i: Integer; ThreadID: Integer) begin { do something} end);

Comment: I think a library solution (Omni is the obvious choice) has some advantages. For a start this code, no offence intended, has performance issues. It's expensive to create and destroy threads every time you call ParallelFor.  Better is to have a pool waiting ready to go.  It's also a mistake to call WaitFor in a loop, you should use once of the multiple object wait functions in Win32. The critical section is wasteful - interlocked increment is better. These can be significant issues when the tasks are small.  There is also no handling of exceptions which is a significant omission.

Comment: It is obvious that a library solution has advantages. I indicated that in my answer. But sometimes you need just a simplest solution. Personally, I don't think that creating and destroying threads is bad. Maybe it's a little bit slower (in most cases you didn't even notice this) but i don't like creating objects, especially if you won't use them at all in some cases. You can handle exceptions in your anonymous method.

Comment: @Linas You don't want to be forced to handle exceptions in your anonymous method. But they have to be handled in the thread of course. What you want is for the exception to get back out into the main thread. Sure creating/destroying threads is no problem for long running tasks, but for short tasks it is a big expense.

Comment: @Linas I must admit I use my own thread pool class that pre dates Omni and have had to deal with a lot of these issues. I periodically wonder if I should look into Omni and see if it offers benefits.

Comment: Well, for short tasks maybe it is better to not use the threads. I am also using thread pool for more complex situations. I just wanted to show quite simple piece of code how parallel for could be implemented.

Comment: There are at least three advantages OmniThreadLibrary Parallel.ForEach has over this solution (and I'm not saying that this Linas's solution is bad). 1) OTL will use thread pool for thread execution. 2) OTL tasks will steal work from other tasks if they finish prematurely. 3) OTL Parallel.ForEach can preserve input ordering (not execution ordering but result ordering).

Comment: @linas do you know (or tested) if your solution works on the other target platforms of Delphi XE5? I know that Omni library does not work because it relies on windows api. I need something simples, that is when opening form let some slow data queries run in parallel to fill less important areas of the form.

Comment: @eelias I don't see why it shouldn't work. The only change you could need is to replace InterlockedIncrement call with TInterlocked.Increment and InterlockedDecrement with TInterlocked.Decrement.