# Delphi FireMonkey Canvas performance issues

Tags: delphi, canvas, firemonkey

I am trying to make 2D game in Delphi XE5/XE6 with FireMonkey, and I need to keep multiplatformity - I need Windows and Android build. For now, game is just drawn with lines, circles, rectangles or other polygons and I use Canvas (`TPaintBox` on whole screen and OnPaint event to paint). Problem is, I think that performance is extremely low, even when FireMonkey should use GPU acceleration. I made this performance test which draw 1000 rectangles on random XY positions:

```
procedure Paint(Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  I: Integer;
  X, Y: Single;
begin
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  Canvas.Clear($ffffffff);

  Canvas.Fill.Color := $ffff0000;
  for I := 0 to 10000 do begin
    X := Random(500);
    Y := Random(400);
    Canvas.FillRect(TRectF.Create(X, Y, X + 20, Y + 20), 0, 0, [], 1);
  end;

  Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

I measured approach thru this function and I get these results:

- Windows PC - Core2Duo 3.2GHz, GeForce 660Ti - pretty strong for such simple task - **it took 20 miliseconds**
- Android Phone - HTC One X (4 core, 1 GHz, Tegra 3 CPU/GPU) - **it took 50-60 milisends** (not as big difference against PC, as i thought)

However I think that both devices should be able to draw not 10 000, but 100 000, or even milions rectanges (my PC with GTX 660 Ti for sure) in one frame (assuming at least 25 FPS, so in about 40 miliseconds), but I can reach this with FireMonkey, even when Delphi creators brags that it is lightnight fast and GPU accelerated. And if I replace rectangle with circle (FillArc method), when I draw 100 circles, it took about same time as 10 000 rectangles. Same with outputing letters (one-char texts). What am I doing wrong? Is there any mistake I can't see? Or it is just problem of FireMonkey? Or it is normal?

What another way I should choose than Canvas for fast drawing when I need to keep compatibility with Windows and Android?

Answer (score 2):

The Firemonkey canvas on Windows is probably not using the GPU. If you are using XE6 you can

> set the global variable FMX.Types.GlobalUseGPUCanvas to true in the initialization section.

[Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.GlobalUseGPUCanvas)

Otherwise, in XE5 stick a TViewPort3D on your Form. Stick a TLayer3D in the TViewPort3D and change it's to Projection property to pjScreen. Stick your TPaintBox on the TLayer3D.

Another alternative could be there is an [OpenGL canvas unit](https://github.com/FMXExpress/box2d-firemonkey/blob/master/OpenGL%20Canvas/UOpenGLCanvas.pas)

You could also parallel process your loop but they will only make your test faster and maybe not your real world game ([Parallel loop in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390149/how-to-realize-parallel-loop-in-delphi))

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this before, i saw little difference in image (less antialiasing), but it did not help that much with circles, lines and text. However, in rectangle test above it really helps - from 20ms it is 1-2ms now. However, no difference in Android (that should use GPU since XE5 or earlier). Now, 200 000 rectangles per frame in Windows is fine ... but still, circles and text is slowing down really bad. Maybe it is not optimized for GPU. I will look to OpenGL alternatives you sent me, thanks.

Comment: Now I tried draw rectangles with this:

`SetLength(Poly, 4);
Poly[0] := TPointF.Create(X, Y);
Poly[1] := TPointF.Create(X + 20, Y);
Poly[2] := TPointF.Create(X + 20, Y + 20);
Poly[3] := TPointF.Create(X, Y + 20);
Canvas.FillPolygon(Poly, 1);`

instead of this:

`Canvas.FillRect(TRectF.Create(X, Y, X + 20, Y + 20), 0, 0, [], 1);`

I think I will need this, because I need to draw rectangles with some angle, but FillRect does not support angle. But even with GPU rendering on, this method is about 900x slower! I could help myself with 2 triangles, but I can't find even fast native triangle method.

Comment: Try using [TPathData](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Graphics.TPathData_Methods). Example: var GPath: TPathData; 
procedure DrawEllipse(Canvas: TCanvas; aRect: TRectF; aOpacity: Single);
begin
  GPath.Clear;
  GPath.AddEllipse(aRect);
  Canvas.DrawPath(GPath, aOpacity);
end;

Comment: Use Win64 on Windows as well. Way faster than Win32.

Comment: [FireMonkey canvas classes](http://itinerantdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/01/firemonkey-canvas-classes-and-bugfix-to.html). Also take a look at TForm.Quality as it has a HighPerformance and HighQuality option.

Answer (score 0):

When you draw a circle in canvas (ie GPUCanvas) then you draw in fact around 50 small triangles. this is how GPUCanvas work. it's even worse with for exemple Rectangle with round rect. I also found that Canvas.BeginScene and Canvas.endScene are very slow operation. you can try to put form.quality to highperformance to avoid antialiasing, but i didn't see that it's change really the speed.